# Get product collection filter by from and to date in magento2.

Tags: magento2

I want to get product collection filter by **From date** and **to date**. How can I get this?

I have used below code in my phtml file so I get all product collection.

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
//echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}
```

Right now I have used **`addAttributeToSelect('*')`** so I am getting all product collection but I want to filter these collection by **from date** and **to date**.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 5):

Inject class `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $stdlibDateTime` 
For example your collection have field `from_date` and `to_date`

```
    // init current time now
    $currentTime = $this->stdlibDateTime->date();

    // Filter datetime
    $collections = $this->getResourceCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('from_date', ['lteq' => $currentTime])
        ->addFieldToFilter('to_date', ['gteq' => $currentTime])
        ->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC')
        ->getData();
```

Comment: I want to get product's special price's **from and to date** how can I do it?

Comment: how can I inject **\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone $_stdTimezone** and **\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $stdlibDateTime** in phtml file?

Comment: You can inject all those classes in your Block Class or Models and call collection into templates by `$block->getCollection()` for example

Comment: if you know how to get **from and to date** filter in collection then please write code here. I don't think you code work.

Comment: Why do you inject `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime` if you don't use it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('2023-09-1')); // start range
 $endDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2023-10-1')); // end range

$collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('from_date', array('gteq',$startDate)); //Date attribute filter
 ->addAttributeToFilter('to_date', array('lteq',$endDate)); //Date attribute filter

if($collection->getSize() > 0){
    foreach ($collection as $product){
        //enter code here
    }
}
```